# CSS: Transparent text in layer over image?

Tags: css, transparency, transparent, layer

I have an image with a text layer over it.
I want the text in the layer to be transparent so that the image shines through.

```
<div class="imgBox">
    <div class="layer">X</div>
    <img src="http://www.eronn.net/camera/test-chart/hue-saturation%20test%20chart%201.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layer {
    position:absolute; left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#ddd;
    opacity:0.5;
    color:#aaa; /* make transparent */
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/6X5JF/

Comment: what do you mean by "shines through"?

Comment: As if the X was cut out of the background.

Comment: not possible AFAIK, a workaround is by using image (solid block with "text cut-out")

Comment: `background: transparent;`

Comment: Context / usage doen't matter. Just style :D

Comment: see here: http://blog.ericzhang.com/punch-through-text-masks-with-css-and-html5/ canvas stuff is new to me but it looks good for creating images programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `rgba()`.

```css
.layer {
    position:absolute; left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:rgba(170,170,170,.5); /* make transparent */
}
```

**EDIT:** Like a plus. I don't know if this is what you was refering, but I will add it just like me playing with something.
I feel now that you wanted something like this, preserving the transparent layout visible, without deleting it or making it 100% invisible (according what you said to Imamul).
I made a little change in the html, making the text applied with `.layer:after`. The problem of this is that, at this moment, it **only works in Firefox and safari** :p So, like I said, only add this like a plus, or curiosity, not like a "solution". It uses the `mix-blend-mode` property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). Don't punish me :p If you change position of `.layer`, you can see how text blend with `.layer` and how it seems to reflect the background image. Isn't the same color, but it's interesting, no? You can play with it and different blending modes. Some day, I hope this will be supported in others browsers.

*Note:* on Firefox, you need to change `layout.css.mix-blend-mode.enabled` to `true`.

You can view it in action in http://jsfiddle.net/soulchainer/nVm5j/5/

```css
.layer {
position:absolute; left:0;
width:100px;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
font-size:5em;
font-weight:bold;
background:#ddd;
opacity:0.5;
color:#aaa; /* make transparent */
mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.layer:after {
    content:"X";
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Anyways, for the real thing that seems you want to do, maybe the best solution would be using a "empty font", a creative font with only border visible. But you again will have the problem of that background of `.layer` if you don't make it 100% transparent.

Comment: Doesn't make the image shine through :/

Comment: @Martin can you tell difference in between : http://jsfiddle.net/mjy8w/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/mjy8w/1/ screen shot at http://i.stack.imgur.com/oDpFf.jpg

Comment: Oh. You can down-reputation me again if you want, @GCyrillus, if that's is the motive you removed their down-reputation: was me who up-voted Imamul (obviously, I'm saying him also down-voted him, just I fixed that) . I just consider unfair the down-voted when him even explain himself clearly. He could only comment that that wasn't what he wanted and clarify it, but he first down-voted and later, explain something. I lost any will to help him, and also even didn't bother in reply to it. I'm sorry for the missunderstanding you got because of that.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't my intention. I thought this would down vote the answer. It doesn't let me undo the vote cos it's older than 3 hours.

Comment: Apologies accepted ;) 
Of course, reputation down is here to be used (when needed), but next time be sure to be more clear in your questions. If you see more than one person missunderstanding you, simply edit and clarify your question. Because maybe that's part of the problem. Instead of voting down very fast. It feels... unfair. When you replied "doesn't make the image shine through" I didn't get anything. Like I don't have enought reputation, I didn't cast that down vote (but I wanted). I also haven't enought reputation to comment in answers, so I must risk myself making answers.Greets.

Comment: "shining through" may not be proper English :) Using `rgba(221,221,221,0.8)` for the layer and `color:#fff; opacity:0.8;` for the text now.

Comment: @Martin, just like curiosity, I edit this with something that can be that: a curiosity, because is not well supported between browsers. Maybe also not what you wanted, but... curious xD

Answer (score 1):

remove background propertie from layer class. then it will show only text as transparent.

```
.imgBox:hover .layer {
   opacity:0.1;
```

}

Comment: The hack is to have the layer with the backgound.

Answer (score 1):

add `background:transparent;` to `.layers` notice the text remains Opaque in the demo, because `opacity` is always inherited in CSS, unlike most other properties the inheritance with opacity is strict.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/mjy8w/1/

EDIT: You can't have invisible text with css. you can however use `text-shadow` to create an outline effect. Sorry but what you describe is not possible at this time with css.

Comment: Thanks, the text uses a lighter color than the background now with even lighter text-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

you can try accomplishing this by using -webkit-background-clip:text

```
body {
  background: url(YOUR BG IMG);
}
.time { 
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
span { 
  background: url(YOUR BG IMG);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```